# Simple audiobooks/books which are not “Learn French” books

Tags: ressources, littérature

I live in Flanders (Belgium) and I've **studied French for many years at school**, but I wasn't really interested and not trying very hard. So I've lost a lot of potential, but now I really want to start learning French. I **still know the basics and can understand the major lines in newspaper articles** if I really try and concentrate. Let's say I have an **A2 level** at the moment, because I barely use it.

I was listening English audiobooks on my way to work (2 hours a day in total) and it got me thinking. Maybe you guys know some good **French audiobooks/books** which are **not too complex and too fast**. So I can start easy and listen more complex ones in time. I would want to listen/read real stories (perhaps even real French classics) and not like these 'Learn French' books.

I guess 2 hours of listening French each day will be a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a French classic but the Harry Potter saga in French could be suited for your current level of French (although maybe "too easy"... ? Can't really say, I'm not used to the A/B/C-levels).

Some books from Voltaire (*Candide, Zadig*) or Victor Hugo (*Les Misérables*) might as well suit you. I would recommend *Candide* to begin with.

Comment: I also thought about Harry Potter at first (because I'm a huge fan), but I thought it would be hard because the frequent use of uncommon and special words. But I can give it a try and I'll definitely search the other 2 as well. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Well IIRC, the sentences and the words used in Harry Potter are not too complex. Of course, there will be some hard words or complex sentences structures here and there, but nothing too difficult if you already did some French at school. The other books I suggested are a bit harder than Harry Potter.

Comment: Okay good to know. Then I'll start with Harry Potter if you say they are easier.

Comment: Do you have any idea where to get these? I can only find a few which are €25 each, that's more expensive than the books

Answer (score 2):

Try *Le Petit Prince* de Saint-Exupéry, par [Gérard Philippe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16KDvWdiiug).

Answer (score 0):

"Les comtes du jour et de la nuit" by Guy de Maupassant are also quite simple.

P.S. As for me, to listen to French songs and to look at their lyrics afterward seems useful.